# How To Convert Recursion to Iterative Code (ADLS and Databricks)

Tags: python, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to find the size of directory in ADLS gen 2 container. I've tried one solution using recursion, but I have reached max recursion allowed. I need help with making an iterative solution. Here is my code:

```
%python
from dbutils import FileInfo
from typing import List

def true_size(path: str, verbose: bool = True):
  def loop_path(path: str):
    accum_size = 0.0
    path_list = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
    if path_list:
      for path_object in path_list:
        if path_object.size > 0:
          if verbose:
            print(f"{path_object.path}: {path_object.size / 1e6} MB")
          accum_size += path_object.size / 1e6
        else:
          # Folder: recursive discovery
          accum_size += loop_path(path_object.path)
    return accum_size

  return loop_path(path)
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible ways to convert recursive function to iterative.

**1. Tail-recursive function** - A recursive function is tail recursive when a recursive call is the last thing executed by the function. For example the following C++ function print() is tail recursive. A tail-recursive function doesn't need stack.

**2. Continuation stack** - What's the continuation? It's "return n * _", where that _ is the return value of the recursive call. You can write a function with one argument that does that. (What about the base case? Well, a function of 1 argument can always ignore its argument). So, instead of storing continuations, you can just store functions. Check continuation example [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-do-i-make-recursive-function.html) for more clarification.